# UK Standard Visitor Visa - what is the total amount of money you spend each month

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, nigerian-citizens

[image]

> **REASONS FOR REFUSAL**
>
> You have applied for a visa to visit the UK. In deciding whether you meet the requirements of Appendix V: of the Immigration Rules for visitors
> (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules), I have considered:
>
> - your application and any additional relevant information you have provided with it
> - your immigration history
>
> **The decision**
>
> I have refused your application for a visit visa
> because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of
> paragraph(s) V4.2 of Appendix V because:
>
> You have applied to visit the
> United Kingdom for 16 days for Tourism.
>
> I note that you state your
> father will be paying towards the cost of your visit and you have
> provided supporting information of your father's circumstances.
> However I have to take into account your own current circumstances
> within Nigeria. You state that you are a student and do not have any
> other income. You state that you spend 30000.00 NGN (£56.12) on your
> living expenses per month. However from the information you have
> provided it does not demonstrate that how you support yourself on a
> daily basis. I am not satisfied you have demonstrated your own
> personal circumstances or that they are as such that you can be relied
> upon to meet the requirements of entry clearance as a visitor.
>
> Furthermore you state that you are personally planning to spend
> 100000.00 NGN (£187.07) on your proposed visit to the UK and no one else will be contributing to the costs of your visit. However from the
> information you have provided it has not been demonstrated that you
> have access to funds of your own. As a result I am not satisfied that
> you will have access to funds to support your personal trip costs
> throughout your visit nor that have you provided an accurate
> reflection of your personal and financial circumstances.
>
> In light of
> all of the above, I am not satisfied that you intend to leave the
> United Kingdom or that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor or
> that you have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in
> relation to their visit without working or accessing public funds.
> Your application is therefore refused under paragraph V4.2 (a) and (c)
> of the Immigration Rules.
>
> Rate of exchange £1 = [534.55 NGN]
> (reference [www.oanda.com](http://www.oanda.com) on [29/11/2022]

This is concerning a UK visa. I know someone has asked a similar question, but my issue is that my monthly spendings are not consistent. I also do not have a job and my only "income" is from the money I get as an allowance. Sometimes my mum sends money into my account to hold it for her, which is around 10 times what I normally spend. Sometimes I also win money from betting. Should I make an average of the last six months' expenditure? I'm trying to be as accurate as possible.

I am Nigerian, in my early twenties. I am still in university (I have a letter from my dean) and I am going for a family Christmas vacation. I am staying for two weeks and my dad is paying for everything.

Comment: From what you've said and the cited reasons in the rejection letter, I think that something you wrote in your application might have been misinterpreted. I would guess that English is not your native language, and it may help to get a native speaker to review the wording and phrasing of your application to help you.

Comment: @Douglas there was a whole segment in the application  where I had to write information about my dad (sponsor) so I don’t know how they missed that and wrongfully accused me of saying no one else was contributing towards the trip

Comment: @Douglas I have also attached a picture the application I submitted in the post  as proof that they wrongfully stated that I stated that no one else was paying for my visit. I cannot appeal it but they have lied against me

Comment: You should state the amount of **regular** allowance that you get from your parents in the *Do you have another income or any savings* section. If your allowance varies, I recommend you state the *average* over a year and provide a breakdown of exactly what payments you get. These payments must tie up with a) the amounts shown in your parents’ bank statements, and b) the amounts shown in yours.

Comment: Also, if you’re travelling as a family do your parents already have their UK visas (assuming they need one)? If yes, did you mention that in your application (or x-reference to their visa application if it is in progress)? Did you provide a sponsorship letter from your father?

Answer (score 16):

This may not directly answer your question, but reading it I went "Ouch!", so some advice...

I think it's important you remember that applying for a visa is not like applying for a passport. It's not just a matter of filling out an application form and providing the required documents, and that's it, you get it.

It's more like applying for a loan, or trying to get a job, or applying for a top university. **You have to convince them it's a good idea for them to give you a visa**.

Visas are not a right. Countries get to pick who they want to let in or not, and they mostly want to be sure that:

- You will leave the country at the end of your planned trip
- You won't need to work or rely on public funds during your stay.

That's why they ask all those questions. Their goal is to ascertain:

- That you have a good reason to go back home. That often means a stable, well-paid job (in comparison to wages in the UK, not at home), or studies to return to, or other strong links to your home country (a family to support, property, a business to run...)
- That you have the required funds to pay for your trip. Either you have enough disposable income (your wages less your outgoings), or you have significant savings, or someone else is paying for you.

For the first point, you're saying you don't have a job, so that takes out the best reason. You need to have a good reason to return home, otherwise your visa will be denied.

For the second point, since you apparently don't have any income, how are you paying for the trip? Or who is? If someone else is paying for it, you need to provide details for their financial situation.

Also, you state that "Sometimes my mum sends money into my account to hold it for her which is like 10 times what I normally spend". This is a huge red flag, as it can be considered "funds parking". They like to see regular, consistent income, not irregular deposits.

I strongly recommend you read [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) and [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/92122/30703).

A majority of your outgoings should be quite consistent: rent, utilities, food... Is that not the case? Are you still living with your parents maybe?

You really need to paint a picture that shows it's in the UK's interest to let you in. Sure, if you're the heir of a (non-Russian) gazillionaire they probably don't care about your income or your outgoings or anything at all. But if you're just an average person, you need to show that you match their requirements, and pay attention to all the red flags (and there are many in your case).

Also remember that if you're not sure your application is good enough, you probably shouldn't submit it. It's not like "I'll submit this and see what gives, and if they say no I'll retry a bit later". They have a memory, and first impressions last. Once you have a rejection, they will look at further applications with even more of a suspicious eye than a first application.

And finally, remember that some countries will ask for visa refusals from any other country, so it won't be a problem just for the UK, it may prevent you from getting visas from other countries as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate you for taking time to reply. 

First of all, I don’t have a job because I’m still a student in university. I got a letter from my dean to prove that I am still very much a student. I am visiting UK for the school break. I live with my parents.  I was refused visa because I didn’t add bank statements. I assumed my fathers(who is paying for everything) bank statements would be the only thing necessary. The “income” is receive is actually an allowance which is once or twice a month. I also use those allowance to win more money sometimes.

Comment: @Venna You write "I was refused visa because..." What country refused your visa application? When did this occur? The answer's second-to-last paragraph is important.

Comment: @Venna is the betting legal?  There's a law in the UK that requires immigration officers to determine that all of your income comes from legitimate sources.  They'll probably also be wondering why your mother holds her money in your account when she obviously has enough of it to open her own account.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica UK. I was refused last month. I didn’t attach my bank statements because I assumed my dad’s bank statement would be all I need. They stated their reasons.. the summary of their reasons is that I didn’t show how I support myself and I didn’t show I have access to my funds

Comment: @phoog yes it is legal

Comment: @phoog I didn’t mean she doesn’t have an account. She has her own account and she sends me money sometimes

Comment: @Venna Did you state in your application that you are a student, that you still live with your parents, and that your father is paying for the trip? Did you include the letter from your dean in the application?

Comment: @Douglas. I stated all of those things. It seems they lied against me or made a mistake and said that I stated that no one else was covering the trip when it was clearly stated in the application that my father would cover everything. I think my only problem was not including a bank statement. I only included the allowance I received as what I spend(in the application). I wish I could send you a picture of the refusal letter

Comment: @Venna It's important you understand that you start with quite a handicap: Nigeria is consistently in the top 10 countries with the highest UK visa refusal rate. You are young, don't have a job, have few ties to your home country, so in their eyes you match the profile of someone who would pretend to come for a holiday but then stay in the UK and work illegally, so they'll find any excuse to say no. The fact that the trip is paid by your parents, that you are visiting with them should help, but apparently that wasn't enough in your first application, and now with a previous refusal it's harder

Comment: @Venna Did you all apply for visas together?

Comment: @Venna V 4 (a) and (c) refusals are discussed in the [second link}(https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/92122/30703) in user jcaron's Answer. Many of the points in that discussion apply to your application. For example: is "Professor [name obscured]" your father? Your words "someone I know" and "family" vacation are imprecise. The application shows no statement that your father will pay for your trip. ₦1M seems hardly enough to transport a family roundtrip to the UK and return, much less support them while in the UK. This is not a strong presentation.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I believe many of the answers are actually preset choices, not free text inputs. Also the amount given is what the applicant will _personnally_ pay, not the total cost of the trip. The application form is not necessarily very easy to navigate for dependents, and I don’t remember if the UK allows joint applications for the whole family, but it really looks like they just went with their _a priori_ and decided that young Nigerian is just a no no. Not sure it would really be very easy to overcome that.

Comment: @jcaron You may well be correct. To present a complete application in the face of required presets will be a challenge. I think the OP doesn't yet grasp that they must _sell_ their application, rather than merely select from presets or recite to a formula.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica “someone I know” is not my words. It is an option in the UK visa application form online. There isn’t much provision for self expression.  As I’m not paying anything, what amount do I put?

Comment: @Venna I believe there is an opportunity for applicants to add information explaining their circumstances.

Comment: @jcaron if you’re fully sponsored, should the amount in the “how much are you spending personally” and “how much is your sponsor contributing towards your trip” section of the visa application form be the same?